# Data from Table to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Good day,

I have a table with data that I was trying to convert into a json format so i can print it with my JSPDF plugin but the problem is I cant seem to insert the proper json format into my existing json data.

here is my script that convert table data into json

```
$('.report-table tr').each(function(){
        var obj = {};
        obj['column'] = [{}];
        obj['column']['value']=[];

        $('th', this).each(function(){ 
            //obj.column.value.push($(this).text()); 
            obj['column']['value'] = $(this).text();   
            // obj.column.value.push($(this).text()); 
            // obj['column'] = $(this).text(); 
        }); 


        $('td', this).each(function(){

            // obj.column.value.push($(this).text()); 
            obj['column']['value'] = $(this).text(); 


        });    

       dynamic.contents.data.push(obj);

    });
```

this is my existing json data that i want to be appended

```
var dynamic = {
"documentTitle": "Dynamic Print",
"pageTitle": "Dynamic Print",
"image": '',
"pageType": "d",
"columns": 5,
"contents": {
    "data": [
        {
            "column": [
                {
                    "value": "Jan.2007"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Jan.2008"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Jan.2009"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Jan.2010"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Period End"
                }
            ],
            "header": true,
            "fontType": "b",
            "highLight": 1,
            "newLine": 1
        },
        {
            "column": [
                {
                    "value": "-95000100"
                },
                {
                    "value": "85411250"
                },
                {
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "value": "55000250"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Dynamic print 1 Dynamic print 1 Dynamic Dynamic print 1Dynamic print 1print 1"
                }
            ],
            "indent": 1
        },
        {
            "column": [
                {
                    "value": "95000100"
                },
                {
                    "value": " "
                },
                {
                    "value": "55000250"
                },
                {
                    "value": "55000250"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Dynamic print 1 Dynamic print 1 Dynamic Dynamic print 1Dynamic print 1print 1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "column": [
                {
                    "value": "95000100"
                },
                {
                    "value": "85411250"
                },
                {
                    "value": "55000250"
                },
                {
                    "value": "55000250"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Dynamic print 1 "
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "column": [
                {
                    "value": "95000100"
                },
                {
                    "value": "85411250"
                },
                {
                    "value": "55000250"
                },
                {
                    "value": "55000250"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Dynamic print 1 "
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "hr": 1,
            "highLight": 1,
            "column": [
                {
                    "value": "95000100"
                },
                {
                    "value": "85411250"
                },
                {
                    "value": "55000250"
                },
                {
                    "value": "55000250"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Dynamic print 1 "
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "column": [
                {
                    "value": "95000100"
                },
                {
                    "value": "85411250"
                },
                {
                    "value": "55000250"
                },
                {
                    "value": "55000250"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Dynamic print 1 "
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
};
```

so the problem is i want to get this data format [image]

but im getting this kind of format from my js [image]

can anyone please help me to do the proper formatting. Thank you very much! Please Let me know if there is something I can do to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is visible at the very beginning. You have there those two lines:

```
    obj['column'] = [{}];
    obj['column']['value']=[];
```

The first one makes `obj['column']` an array with empty object at 0-th position. At the second line you access the `value` property of `obj['column']` making it an object instead of an array, and that is I guess undesired result. I think you want to make `obj['column']` a simple array and in that array you want to push a object with property `value`, like this:

```
obj['column'] = [];
obj['column'].push({value: []});
```

Or even better you don't want to push anything at the `obj['column']` at this point, but in the `.each()` methods:

```
    obj['column'] = [];

    $('th', this).each(function(){ 
        obj['column'].push({value: $(this).text()});   
    });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Drecker!! It works! I cant believe that it would be that easy, I did spent several hours working on that one until I decided to post it here! Again thank you very much for your help! really did saved me. Now I can proceed to the next thing! :) :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this perhaps:

obj['column'].push({'value': $(this).text()});

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Sir @Marty McKeever! yeah thats the proper way of doing it!